# how to create this effect using photoshop (the black to colored one)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

[image: jersey]
how to create this kind of texture or effect in a jersey design or from solid to tranparency

Comment: Isn't that just a gradient? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need transparency in print jobs generally, as there isn't usually any white ink in the process. Check with your printer about the printing process being used.  If it's just regular single colour screen printing, you don't have to worry about transparency.

In Photoshop, open a new greyscale image.  Make a gradient from black to white.

Click *Filter > Pixelate > Color Halftone*, and set it up as shown below. Of course you can change the radius or angle as you wish.

[image]

Comment: Informative answer! Screen printing has its own quirks, one being that the traditional method required a positive film to burn the film that gets applied to the screen (rather than a negative as required to burn offset printing plates). The print shop should of course be able to give its requirements.